# Broken image links on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is a strange behavior on a WP site with woocommerce plugin. Some URLs of product images randomly stopped being available, but sometimes the images are not available from the beginning. All the URL has the prefix i3.wp.com, however there is no plugin installed like jetpack, Photon or CDN (AFAIK these plugins could cause this issue). Without the prefixes, all the images are working. The issue started a long time ago, I just updated to WP 4.1 with PHP 7.2 but the problem it still persists.

Comment: Perhaps Jetpack has been installed once? Do you have a Cache plugin which could have saved the prefix?

Comment: I have installed an SSL certificate and it seems the problem solved. Hope it won't came out of blue again.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still stands. I have a plugin called WP Fastest Cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the WP Fastest Cache plugin, CDN settings, I removed the integration. Now URLs don't have prefixes.